# How to unset session in <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, php

is it possible to unset a `$_session` in the `<script>` tag??
i have this script (for the checkout), and after it pop up, and clicked "ok" it will clear my cart using `unset($_SESSION['cart'])`; how can i do that? thanks.

```
echo "<script> alert('Thank You For Ordering! We will Keep in Touch!');window.location='cart.php';</script>";
```

Comment: This isn't possible, due to the way PHP and javascript are rendered on the server and browser, respectively. Check out this for more info (and some possible solutions for you): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming

Comment: PHP runs on the server, JS runs on the client. you can't have JS change anything in PHP otehr than by doing an AJAX request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im not sure if you can do that, but you can do like this.

```
echo "<script> alert('Thank You For Ordering! We will Keep in Touch!');
        window.location='unset.php';</script>";
```

your `unset.php`

```
<?php 
     unset($_SESSION['session index']); 
     header('Location: cart.php'); 
?>
```

Comment: i tried this, but still didn't empty my cart

Comment: show the `unset.php` file.

Comment: hey im sorry! i just forgot to include my db.php in unset.php, now it worked!! thank you very much!

Comment: please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: sorry, i'm new here, how can i make your comment the best answer?? because you solved it! your answer helped me thank you!

Comment: you have accepted the answer. That makes answer as best one.:)

Comment: okay, again, Thank you very much! @niranjan

Comment: Welcome. Glad it helped you:)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot unset session on the client-side (in Javascript), because session data is held on server.

You can call server to tell it to unset the session (either redirect or AJAX call will work).

You could, in theory, delete the session cookie on client side, if you want to avoid communicating with server at that moment, but there's couple catches:

- It relies on you knowing name of the session cookie and on it not changing someday
- It relies on session ID being stored in a cookie (they can be stored as request parameter, and in future other way may be adopted)
- It doesn't actually free the data held on server associated with that session, consuming server's resources needlessly

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just clear the session ID cookie?

```
document.cookie="PHPSESSID=''";
```